# How to get values from different forms in Apex

Tags: apex-code

I have a single visual source page where i including a 2 pages through composition, body changes dynamically based on the action of the buttons. Button which is available in wizardButton (like next & previous). So now there are 2 forms available in page.

1. The form available in wizardBody
2. Another form available in wizardButton

Currently i'm able to navigate the pages back and forth, but the problem is not able to take the form values of the body when click the buttons in wizardButtons.

Even i tried with parameters in the controllers to get the value.

Could somebody help me how to solve this issue. Kindly let me know in case of any further details

```
<apex:page label="CreationWizard" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" title="Creation Wizard" controller="WizardController">

  <!- Body differs based on the action button -->
  <apex:composition template="{!wizardBody}" /> 
  <apex:composition template="{!wizardButton}"/>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: This might be better asked on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: i requested my query even in the above link